# How to use the WebGL Overlay View functionality of google maps in a flutter application

Tags: flutter, google-maps, webgl

I have been trying to create an app that can view and draw on top of the vector map from Google's Maps v3 API using Flutter. I created a sample of what I want to do in Javascript and am now trying to recreate that example in Flutter.

I am using several packages to attempt to recreate this functionality in Flutter, but so far have been unsuccessful.

**Here are those Packages:**

google_maps - This is an unofficial google maps package that does include the ability to use the vector maps, as well as the WebGLOverlayView class that I need to draw on top of them.

three_dart - This is a package meant to replicate ThreeJS in Dart. I used ThreeJS in the Javascript project to create and place objects on top of the google map view.

flutter_gl - This package is leveraged by the three dart package and provides an API for OpenGL. In my dart project, I am using it to generate a rendering context which the three dart package can make use of.

Using these packages, I have managed to get flutter to render a vector version of the Google Map that is fully functional as expected. The specific issue that I am having is coming when I try to draw on top of the map. At the moment I have a button to place a sphere onto the map. I can see the sphere pop-up but after what seems to be a single frame, it disappears. If I press the button a second time, I do not see the sphere render for even a single frame. I haven't been able to discern why or how this is happening.

## My Work:

In order to run the example code I will provide here you will need a google maps api key with vector maps enabled. You will also need the associated mapID

Here is the javascript that I am trying to recreate in flutter.
**NOTE: you need to replace the string on line 10 with your API key's mapID. You will also probably need to launch a web server to get this running, I personally am using the "live server" VSCode extension**

```
import * as three from 'three';
        
const sydney = { lat: -33.895, lng: 151.174};
const arizona = { lat: 35.052, lng: -114.464};
const mapOptions = {
  'tilt': 10,
  'heading': 0,
  'zoom': 18,
  'center': sydney,
  'mapId': "YOUR MAP ID HERE"
}

let renderer;
const WebGLOverlayView = new google.maps.WebGLOverlayView();
let scene = new three.Scene();
let camera = new three.PerspectiveCamera();
let sphereCount = 0;
  
// Request needed libraries.
//@ts-ignore
const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions)

function initWebGLOverlayView(map) 
{

    WebGLOverlayView.onAdd = () => {
        // add an ambient light to the scene
        const ambientLight = new three.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.75);
        scene.add(ambientLight);
        };

    WebGLOverlayView.onContextRestored = ({gl}) => {
      // initialize the renderer
      renderer = new three.WebGLRenderer({
        canvas:gl.canvas,
        context: gl,
        ...gl.getContextAttributes(),
      });

      renderer.autoClear = false;
    };

    WebGLOverlayView.onDraw =({gl, transformer}) => {
      
      const latLngAltitudeLiteral = {
        lat: mapOptions.center.lat,
        lng: mapOptions.center.lng,
        altitude: 0
      }

      const matrix = transformer.fromLatLngAltitude(latLngAltitudeLiteral);
      camera.projectionMatrix = new three.Matrix4().fromArray(matrix);

      WebGLOverlayView.requestRedraw();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      renderer.resetState();
    };

    WebGLOverlayView.setMap(map);
}

/* creates a sphere and adds it to the scene with
 the specified position, scale, color, and name */
function addSphere(vector, scale, color, name)
{
  // create the sphere mesh, also setting the color
  const sphereGeo = new three.SphereGeometry();
  const sphereMaterial = new three.MeshBasicMaterial({color: color});
  const sphere = new three.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMaterial);

  // set the sphere position, scale, and name
  sphere.position.set(...vector);
  sphere.scale.set(...scale)
  sphere.name = name !== null ? name : `sphere ${sphereCount}`;
  sphereCount = name !== null ? sphereCount + 1 : sphereCount;

  scene.add(sphere)
}

// initialize the webGlOverlayView callbacks and set its map to the google map instance
initWebGLOverlayView(map);

// setup a button to place a sphere when clicked
let button = document.getElementById("sphereButton");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  addSphere([0,0,100], [5,5,5], 0x000000, null);
})
```

Here is the accompanying html file for the above JS script
**NOTE: on line 4 you need to replace the "YOUR API KEY HERE" with your google maps api key. You will also need to ensure that the script src on line 15 matches whatever you named the file you pasted the above JS code into**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
  <head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR API KEY HERE"></script>
    <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.152.2/build/three.module.js",
          "GLTFLoader": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.152.2/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js",
          "@googlemaps/three": "https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/three/dist/index.esm.js"
        }
      }
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="./test.js"></script>

    <title>google maps test</title> 
  </head>

  <body id = "app" style="height:730px;width:1500px"> 
    <div id="map" style="height:90%;width:90%"></div>
    <button id= "sphereButton">add Sphere</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my working recreation in Flutter. You should be able to just paste this into the main.dart file of a new project
**NOTE: you need to replace the string on line 155 with your map ID**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gl/openGL/opengl/OpenGLContextWeb.dart';
import 'package:google_maps/google_maps.dart';
import 'package:three_dart/three3d/cameras/index.dart';
import 'package:three_dart/three3d/geometries/index.dart';
import 'package:three_dart/three3d/lights/ambient_light.dart';
import 'package:three_dart/three3d/materials/index.dart';
import 'package:three_dart/three3d/math/index.dart';
import 'package:three_dart/three3d/objects/index.dart';
import 'package:three_dart/three3d/renderers/index.dart';
import 'package:three_dart/three3d/renderers/webgl/index.dart';
import 'package:three_dart/three3d/scenes/index.dart';
import 'package:three_dart/three3d/textures/index.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:three_dart/three_dart.dart' as three;
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter_gl/flutter_gl.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GMap? _map;
  final WebGLOverlayView _overlay = WebGLOverlayView();
  final PerspectiveCamera _camera = three.PerspectiveCamera();
  final Scene _scene = three.Scene();
  WebGLRenderer? _renderer;

  void initWebGlOverlayView()
  {
    _overlay.onAdd = ()
    {
      // add an ambient light to the scene
      AmbientLight light = three.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
      _scene.add(light);
    };

    _overlay.onContextRestored = (WebGLStateOptions? stateOptions)
    {
      // initialize the renderer
      Map<dynamic, dynamic>? temp = stateOptions?.gl?.getContextAttributes();
      Map<String,dynamic> contextAttributes = {};

      for (String key in temp!.keys) {
        contextAttributes[key] = temp[key];
      }
      FlutterGlPlugin flutterGl = FlutterGlPlugin();

      Map<String, dynamic> flutterGlOptions = {
        'width': stateOptions?.gl?.drawingBufferWidth,
        'height': stateOptions?.gl?.drawingBufferHeight,
        'dpr': 1.0,
        'canvas': stateOptions?.gl?.canvas,
        'gl': stateOptions?.gl,
      }..addAll(contextAttributes);

      flutterGl.initialize(options: flutterGlOptions).then((value)
      {
        flutterGl.prepareContext().then((value)
        {
          flutterGl.gl.gl = stateOptions?.gl;
          Map<String, dynamic> renderOptions = {
            'width': stateOptions?.gl?.drawingBufferWidth,
            'height': stateOptions?.gl?.drawingBufferHeight,
            'canvas': stateOptions?.gl?.canvas,
            'gl': flutterGl.gl,
          }..addAll(contextAttributes);

          _renderer = three.WebGLRenderer(renderOptions);
          _renderer?.autoClear = false;
          _overlay.onDraw = _onDraw;
        });
      });
    };

    _overlay.map = _map;
  }

  void _onDraw( WebGLDrawOptions? drawOptions)
  {

    LatLngAltitudeLiteral anchorPoint = LatLngAltitudeLiteral()
      ..lat = -33.895
      ..lng = 151.174
      ..altitude = 0;

    Float64List? matrixList = drawOptions?.transformer?.fromLatLngAltitude(anchorPoint as LatLngAltitude);
    _camera.projectionMatrix = three.Matrix4().fromArray(matrixList);

    _overlay.requestRedraw();
    _renderer?.render(_scene, _camera);

    // un-commenting this method breaks the map rendering, believe it is required
    // as it is being used in the JS version. Not sure what the problem is as
    // both versions seem to function the same
    //_renderer?.resetState();
  }
  
  void addSphere()
  {
    SphereGeometry sphereGeo = three.SphereGeometry();
    MeshBasicMaterial sphereMaterial = three.MeshBasicMaterial();
    Mesh sphere = three.Mesh(sphereGeo, sphereMaterial);
    sphere.scale.set(50, 50, 50);
    sphere.material.color.set(0x000000);
    sphere.position.set(0,0,100);

    _scene.add(sphere);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory('map-div', (int viewId) {
      DivElement div = DivElement()
        ..id = 'map-div'
        ..style.width = '100%'
        ..style.height = '100%'
        ..style.border = 'none';

      MapOptions options = MapOptions()
        ..center = LatLng(-33.895, 151.174)
        ..zoom = 18
        ..tilt = 10
        ..heading = 0
        ..mapId = "YOUR MAP ID HERE";

      _map = GMap(div, options);

      initWebGlOverlayView();

      return div;
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
                    width: 900,
                    height: 700,
                    child:  HtmlElementView(viewType: 'map-div')
                ),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: addSphere,
              child: const Text("Add Sphere")
          )
        ]
      )

    );
  }
}
```

In addition you will want to add this script element to the index.html file before the flutter script and with your own API key:
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR API KEY HERE"></script>

And you will want to add these dependencies:

- google_maps: ^6.3.0
- three_dart: ^0.0.16
- flutter_gl: ^0.0.21

## Description

Both of the above examples function about the same, once you launch the app, you will see a google map centered on Sydney Australia. You should be able to move, tilt, zoom etc. all the usual vector maps stuff. There will be an "add sphere" button under the map which, upon being clicked, will place a sphere at the same point that the map was centered on upon being created. In JS the sphere will stick around but in the flutter version you have to watch closely as it will flash onto the screen briefly.

[JS maps image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKCsT.jpg)

The sphere in flutter is much bigger to make it easier to catch.

More helpful information:

- The onDraw callback is where the render command happens, it is being called on a constant loop. I have noticed that the sphere blinking in and out of the flutter version seems to only last for exactly one call of this callback. To see this, place a breakpoint somewhere in the addSphere method and let the map start up. Press the "add sphere button". Once the breakpoint triggers, place another breakpoint somewhere in the _ondraw method. upon pressing play, you will hit the onDraw breakpoint, press play again and you should see the sphere appear. From here it will stay on-screen until you exit the onDraw method.
- In the flutter version, you may notice that I have commented out the _renderer.resetState() call on the last line of the onDraw callback. When that call is uncommented, the map will not render, although you will still be able to interact with markers, street-view etc. It is being used in the JS version of things without an issue and after looking through them in the debugger they seem to be functioning the same. I'm not sure what the issue with the dart version is.